# Mysql Join not getting full data in Php

Tags: php, mysql

Hello everyone i have following two tables in mysql

services

```
id      service_name    image
1       ABC             abc.jpg
2       XYZ             xyz.jpg
```

sub_service

```
id      parent_id       service_name
1       2               DEF
2       2               FGH
```

now i want to all record from table "services" and if sub_service exist related to service_id then
result should be in array,How can i do this ? I am using following code but its showing only matching records
but i want all data from table services and match data with sub_service,Where i am wrong ?

```
$this->db->select('s.id,s.service_name,s.image,ss.parent_id,ss.service_name');
                $this->db->from('services s');
                $this->db->join('sub_services ss', 's.id=ss.parent_id.id');
                $query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: You need to add left join.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this with left join

```
$this->db->select('s.id,s.service_name,s.image,ss.parent_id,ss.service_name');
$this->db->from('services s');
$this->db->join('sub_services ss', 's.id=ss.parent_id.id', 'left');
$query = $this->db->get();  
$result = $query->result_array(); // this will return as array
```

Comment: @Muhhamed Shihabudeen Labba A: i want "subservices detail" as array,How can i do this

Comment: This will probably be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494463/retrieve-second-table-as-subarray-in-codeigniter-query

Comment: @JigarBakshi, added the line of code for fetching as array

Comment: In the select field, you are getting all the details of sub service. In the last line, I've added the code to fetch the whole data as array. Now in your controller, you can get this as array. Just print_r($result).

Comment: @MuhammedShihabudeenLabbaA: you are right sir all my data is coming as an array but i want if subservice details(data) as array( array inside array/multidimensional array), kindly tell me how can i do this sir

Comment: @JigarBakshi, have you got the chance to review this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494463/retrieve-second-table-as-subarray-in-codeigniter-query?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 2):

From your code I will assume that you use codeigniter, you should use [left](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=join#CI_DB_query_builder::join) join like this:

```
$this->db->select('s.id,s.service_name,s.image,ss.parent_id,ss.service_name');
$this->db->from('services s');
// add left as a last parametar
$this->db->join('sub_services ss', 's.id=ss.parent_id.id', 'left');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: i want "subservices detail" as array,How can i do this

Answer (score 0):

remove this and try 
s.id=ss.parent_id<del>.id</del>